# I'm having a lot of issues uploading my code to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I'm having a lot of trouble deploying my code to Heroku.

I started by going to the Heroku logs. And, the photo is what was there.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12FNH.png)

So, I ran bundle install and got the error

```
An error occurred while installing pg (1.2.3), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '1.2.3' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.
```

Eventually, I got that corrected. Just decided to work for some reason. Then, however, I started getting another error when trying to deploy. The error was:

```
remote: !   Failed to install gems via Bundler.
4:32
remote: !   Push rejected to brownsapp.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/brownsapp.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/brownsapp.git'
```

I then tried `git push --force heroku`. No dice. Then it came to thinking that it was trying to deploy from the wrong branch. But the main branch is the only branch I have. I checked and made sure. Noticed that the terminal also said

```
Warning - The same version of this code has already been built:
```

So, I ran `git commit --allow-empty -m "Redeploying"` trying to get the app deployed.

No dice. Then I noticed another error saying:

```
Your bundle only supports platforms ["x86_64-darwin-18"] but your local platform
remote:    is x86_64-linux.`
```

So, I ran the command `bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux`

And then the error continued to show. I tried deleting the  Gemfile.lock file. That didn't help either. I'm at a compete loss. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Some bundles only work on the Mac (and not the new one with the M1 chip either): `x86_64-darwin-18` is one of those. You simply can't *use* that one, if you don't have a Mac (an older one).

Comment: @torek i did try removing this from the code, but I unfortunately continued to get the same error.

Comment: Presumably you have to find some *other* bundle that supports your system. I don't actually use heroku so I don't have any further pointers here.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by adding the linux platform to my bundler Gemfile.lock with this commande.

`bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux`

Perhaps you can add it manually. Look for platform in your Gemfile.lock,
see the picture here for help https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLpya.png